# Deploying existing Console Application to Azure

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, dll, deployment

I have a C# program (I'll call it ProgramA) running on an azure VM running windows server, and it references my MVC site. Currently when I make changes to my MVC sites database structure the program on the VM runs into errors as the database structure has changed.

In order to resolve these errors I simply need to stop the service, update the dll, and restart the service. Currently I do this manually, which is awful as it causes downtime. I am looking to automate this deployment.

**UPDATED - DEPLOYING CONSOLE APPLICATION IN CLOUD WITH DEPLOYMENT FROM VS2013**

I was thinking of achieving this by creating a small app to run on the VM to check for updates and perform them, but I am now aware there are easier ways to achieve my goal by deploying my application from VS to run as a service in the cloud.

My app is a console app. I simply want it running in the cloud in a way that makes it easier to deploy. I have found https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/websites-dotnet-deploy-webjobs/#convert, but following the steps leads me to deploying a website and I'm not sure that's what I want. This isn't a website it is simply a console application.

What is the best way of achieving this?

Comment: Silly, but perhaps create a Windows Task to check for updates regurarly? Then run a PowershellScript with it for stopping the services and moving files around.

Comment: you are using cloud, yet creating solutions which are monolithic in nature; you should seriously consider making your code cloud ready and take the bets out of it, you should be able to deploy your service like you would deploy a web app, may be use azure webjobs in place of Services http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IntroducingWindowsAzureWebJobs.aspx

Comment: @BrijRajSingh-MSFT thanks. I'm aware the setup is completely flawed. ProgramA runs as a standalone application on the VM, and simply reads and writes from two service bus messaging queues. What do I need to do/consider to be able to deploy my app with the ease of a web app? Are you referring creating a cloud service in Azure?